# Go install: “Can't load package” (even though GOPATH is set)

Tags: go, installation, package

I'm just getting started with the Go programming language and installed Go using the Windows installer from the website. I tested installation by using `go run hello.go` and that works. The problem comes when I try to build my first program:

```
$ echo $GOROOT
C:\Go\
$ echo $GOPATH
/cygdrive/c/Users/Paul/Documents/Home/go
mkdir -p $GOPATH/src/hello
```

Inside that directory I have a simple `hello.go` program:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("Hello, world.\n")
}
```

The problem comes when I try to build and install:

```
$ go install hello
can't load package: package hello: cannot find package "hello" in any of:
    C:\Go\src\hello (from $GOROOT)
    \cygdrive\c\Users\Paul\Documents\Home\go\src\hello (from $GOPATH)
```

Comment: Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on. It’s also possible to gain a bit of reputation with your answers and vote up the question so it gets more attention, or you could set a bounty on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GOPATH` environment variable must contain valid path.

`\cygdrive\c\Users\Paul\Documents\Home\go\src\hello` is not a valid path on Windows.

Try setting `GOPATH=c:\Users\Paul\Documents\Home\go` instead.